# I need to get the particular values in Flex DataGrid Column

Tags: apache-flex

Let me explain the situation...

dg.selectedItems gives me all the values selected, but if i need one column names value alone then what should i do.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="1" headerText="Email" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dg.selectedItems[itemIndex]["columnName"]
```

itemIndex = the index of the selected item in the array

note: this is if you have allowMultipleSelection = true... if you are only selected a single item/row use dg.selectedItem.  This will return an object of all the columns.

Added full working code example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
   <mx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
    import mx.events.ListEvent;
    import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;
      import mx.collections.*;

      [Bindable]
      private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
         {Artist:'Pavement', Album:'Slanted and Enchanted', Price:11.99},
         {Artist:'Pavement', Album:'Brighten the Corners', Price:12.99},
         {Artist:'Miley Cyrus', Album:'Break Out', Price:10.99}] );


       private function clickItemHandler(event:ListEvent):void{

            if(myGrid.selectedItem != null){
                trace(myGrid.selectedItem["Album"]);
            }

       }

   ]]>
   </mx:Script>

   <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="350" height="200" 
      dataProvider="{dp}" itemClick="clickItemHandler(event);" >
      <mx:columns>
         <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Album" />
         <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Price" />
      </mx:columns> 
   </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: can u tell me how to code it... i mean

dg.selectedItems.userlevel 

I am not getting your input actually.... userlevel here is my data field.

Comment: in your datagrid, are you able to select more than 1 row?

if so you need to use dg.selectedItems[selectedRowIndex]["dataField"]

but if you are only selecting 1 row use:
dg.selectedItem["dataField"]

Comment: myGrid.selectedItem[selectedRowIndex]["Album"]

What is that value actually